# Make a conversation popup from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is like this:

```
Month   Day       Year              Name 
------------------------------------------------
12      2           2016              Jazz
13      5           2016              John
```

I want it to be like

```
    Month i  Day       Year              Name 
    ------------------------------------------------
    12       2           2016              Jazz
    13       5           2016              John
```

And when I click on the "i" , a bubble conversation pops and says "This is the month you will need to register"
This is to show the `i` and make it a button

```
  <th style= "white-space: nowrap">Month  <button id="opener"><i class="fa fa-info" ></i></button></th>
```

And my jquery code is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
})
```

And this div after I close the table

```
<div id=dialog>
<p> This is the month you will need to register </p>
</div>
```

The `i` is a button clickable but nothing pops-up and the HI is shown under the table
And how can I make the bubble

Comment: You almost got it. Just have to add the html for the content of #dialog and include the jquery.css file to apply styles.

Comment: I have jquery included, and didn't I include the content of the #dialog when I put it in the div?

Comment: <div id=dialog>
<p> "Content here" </p>
</div> But all I get is content under the table

Comment: Double quote the id: <div id="dialog">

Comment: I did, it still goes under the table

Comment: To increase your chances of getting an answer, I suggest you create a [mcve].

Comment: @Serena and do you have referenced the jQuery stylesheet?
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: The i button works, and its clickable, however it just doesnt display anything when its clicked, and the content i put inside the div just show up under the table like its part of the table

Comment: I have this <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>  @Dez

Comment: @Serena , you need the jQuery css stylesshet. Add it to the head of your html page.

Comment: I put it, I still get the same output

Comment: I also want it to be a bubble like this: http://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/example.html

Comment: @Serena I think you want a tooltip, not a dialog.

Comment: Actually i want a .popup but its not working Im not sure why